# jQuery div on the fly with background color

Tags: jquery, html, properties, background-color

I wonder if anybody can explain why in the first created div the background color will not work and it does in the second example.

```
$("<div/>", {
width:300,
height:400,
backgroundColor:"#425412", //background-color does not work
text: "hello there"
}).appendTo("body");
```

Note: without the background-color property the div will be created.

```
// works as defined including background-color
$("<div style='width:300; height:400; background-color:#425412;'>hello there</div>").appendTo("body");
```

Does the first method have restrictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the `backgroundColor` property a key of a `css` object.

```
$("<div/>", {
    width:300,
    height:400,
    css: {
        backgroundColor:"#425412"
    },
    text: "hello there"
}).appendTo("body");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zatcZ/).

Comment: Really ... How interesting. Thanks, that's a new one for me..  :-)

Comment: @Daniel: It is rather obscurely described in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2): *As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to jQuery() can accept a map consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the .attr() method. Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: val, css, html, text, data, width, height, or offset. The name "class" must be quoted in the map since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it is not the correct attribute name.*

Comment: Which explains why it doesn't work to just do `backgroundColor` as there is no jQuery method that does this (thus it should be passed into `css` instead).

Comment: @Spoike: it is rather obscure indeed. I tried chaining css, but that obviously didn't work. I would think this is not the least important thing to overlook. Thanks for clearing that up.